# How to pass output value from bat file to c# application?

Tags: c#, batch-file

E.g My bat file would be as follows

```
Test.bat
----------------
some code 
return true/false
----------------
```

Can I read this value back in c# application ?
Is this possible ?

Note: I don't want to use any external file for storing returned value

Comment: What do you mean by "return true/false"? Do you mean it prints out "true" or "false" to the console? Or does it use the exit code to communicate success/failure? (It would be helpful if you'd give a runnable sample rather than just pseudo-code.)

Comment: Are you saying you want the batch file to communicate with an application that is running? did said application start said batch file

Comment: You can either run the batch file from the c# app and read the screen OR send an exit code from the batch file for the c# to pick up..  However more accurate example of what you're trying is needed

Answer (score 0):

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\AssaultCube_v1.1.0.4\assaultcube.bat\"");

processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();

string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

link : [how-to-i-execute-a-bat-file-in-a-c-windows-form](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a06ec27-91c7-4656-9031-2b66f7ddc80e/how-to-i-execute-a-bat-file-in-a-c-windows-form?forum=csharpgeneral)

then You can save **output** to some file